# Why does my datagridview repositions on escape

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView control on a form in a manged c# project. (.net 2.0) 
When I use the scroll button on my mouse and then click a cell and click the escape button or select another cell the grid will reposition it self. But if i use the scrollbar on the control, this behavior does not happen.

Have anyone seen behavior like this before or have any idea to what might cause it?

Answer (score 1):

I've not seen something like that before.

Have you checked your event handlers?

The reason I ask is that taking a minimal application of 1 form, 1 DataGridView, doesn't exhibit this problem.